# PHP proxy for videos - not working on some Apple devices

Tags: php, ios, macos, http

The problem i'm facing is this:

- I have a video on remote server that is loaded on my website
- some users cannot access video because remote server URL is blocked
- I create a proxy in PHP that is loading data from remote server with file_get_contents(), I'm getting headers from remote server and returning for the user response with same headers and content as a remote server.
- Everything is working well on all devices except some Apple devices. It shows empty player with message `Failed to Load Resource, Plugin Handled Load`.

I spend a lot of time on looking for solution, was trying to handle even HTTP range requests with no success. I mange to reproduce error with postman using Safari headers and I manage to handle HTTP range request and video was working on Postman, but not in Safari. The only thing that may solve the issue is downloading file to my server and use the path to file to let nginx serve the file, but it means that I should have some cronjob that will remove file after usage.

So I hope that someone can give me ideas how to "fake" nginx response using PHP, just using headers and regular or streamed response is not enough.